# OracleBulkCopy Class in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll?

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0, odp.net

I am using OracleBulkCopy Class with reference to Oracle.DataAccess.dll. I want to use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll for easy deployment. But then I got build error "OracleBulkCopy not found"

Does anyone know why OracleBulkCopy is not included in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll?

Answer (score 8):

You are correct. At the time of this writing OracleBulkCopy is not supported in ODP.NET, Managed Driver.

The reason is is not included was simply a matter of feature priority. As the Managed Driver becomes more feature complete, eventually the OracleBulkCopy class will be added.

In the future, anyone can look at the "Differences between the ODP.NET Managed Driver and Unmanaged Driver" section of the most recent ODP.NET book to see what is not supported:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/intro004.htm#ODPNT8146

Comment: Curious if Oracle will ship this feature before I retire as developer :(

Comment: @Benni I hear you Benni, the best I can suggest is that you vote for this feature here: http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=18357:46

Answer (score 7):

Please vote for it at the Oracle Feature Request page:

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=18357:39:28710406382793::NO::P39_ID:27881

If we get enough votes, they may implement it.

Comment: I have voted on it, but, no hope of implementation for it. Oracle seens to  does not care about .net provider.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, this feature is part of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client namespace. :)