# How to make a Bulk Insert using Oracle Managed Data Acess c#

Tags: c#, oracle, bulkinsert

I have a `dynamic list object` that i want to `BulkInsert` into my `DB`, i was using the old `OracleBulkCopy` method from another lib, but i can't use that lib anymore and on the new lib i don't have this method.

New lib : `using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;`

Old lib : `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`

Does anyone know a easy way to do the `Bulk` without creating lists or arrays to do it?

Comment: What is the new lib?

Comment: just edit the question and add the libs

Answer (score 12):

The `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` lib doesn't yet support BulkCopy.

You can compare functionality from both libs in the folowing link: [Oracle Managed Driver Comparison](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/intro004.htm#ODPNT8146)

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941161/oraclebulkcopy-class-in-oracle-manageddataaccess-dll)

Another option would be to use [Array Binding](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html).

Example:

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connString = "Data Source=xyz; user id=**; password=**";
            using (var con = new OracleConnection(connString))
            {
                con.Open();
                int[] foos = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
                string[] bars = new string[3] { "A", "B", "C" };

                OracleParameter pFoo = new OracleParameter();
                pFoo.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
                pFoo.Value = foos;

                OracleParameter pBar = new OracleParameter();
                pBar.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                pBar.Value = bars;

                // create command and set properties
                OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into test (foo, bar) values (:1, :2)";
                cmd.ArrayBindCount = foos.Length;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pFoo);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pBar);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know, that's why i ask for a bulk insert while i'm using this lib, has to be a way

Comment: @LucioZenir Have you tried array binding? [Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html)

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders -- are you sure array binding work with the managed client?  For some reason, I thought that was not supported.  I believe you, but we've been using DevArt because we thought it wasn't supported.  If that's not the case, I'd like to switch to the Oracle client.  The article you referenced didn't appear to say one way or the other.

Comment: @Hambone, Yep, tested it just now, it works with the managed client. Edited the answer with a simple example.

Comment: Amazing...  all these years.  Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: This particular example doesn't account scenarios when some data can be NULL

Comment: Overall, this process is working well for me.  I just had a situation where the insert is failing for valid reasons.  I am trying to add a Try/Catch to the code and it is still crashing because the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() seems to be running as a background thread?  I'm not sure how to catch that error?

Answer (score 3):

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client started to support bulk copy since version 19.10
Try to use it for insert!